# Extraindo números de uma String

Tags: java, string

Tenho uma String no seguinte formato:

```
01 - 02 - 03 - 04 - 45 - 86
```

Preciso colocar esses números em um `array int[6]`. Qual a melhor forma de fazer essa operação?

Answer (score 10):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "01 - 02 - 03 - 04 - 45 - 86";
        String[] sp = s.split(" - ");
        int n[] = new int[sp.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
            n[i] = Integer.parseInt(sp[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(" " + n[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Você pode ver a documentação [aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: Obrigado Leornardo funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 4):

Uma alternativa é usar **[expressões regulares](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular)**. Sendo assim, não importa como está os números na sua String, com regex irá extrair para você. Veja abaixo como fica a implementação:

```
String numeros = "05abc474 - 651ssss1120;lks01=9";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(numeros);

StringBuilder nroExtraidos = new StringBuilder();
while (m.find()) {
    nroExtraidos.append(m.group().trim() + "/");
}

System.out.println(nroExtraidos);
```

Saída:

```
05/474/651/1120/01/9/
```

Veja que você pode ter uma String completamente variada entre caracteres e números. Mesmo assim você conseguirá extrair os números.

Answer (score 0):

Oi.
Fiz uma prova de Orientação a Objetos que o objetivo do exercício era receber uma string do tipo "1 + 2 * 4" e separar o que era sinal e o que era numero e apresentar o resultado da operação.

Na prova eu resolvi usando List e com método bolha para fazer efeito pilha nos casos de precedência (multiplicação e divisão).

Minha classe calculadora ficou assim:

class Calculadora {

```
private LinkedList<Character> numeros = new LinkedList<Character>();
private LinkedList<Character> op = new LinkedList<Character>();

Calculadora(String formula) {

    LinkedList<Character> valores = new LinkedList<Character>();

    valores.add('1');
    valores.add('2');
    valores.add('3');
    valores.add('4');
    valores.add('5');
    valores.add('6');
    valores.add('7');
    valores.add('8');
    valores.add('9');
    valores.add('0');

    LinkedList opValidos = new LinkedList();
    opValidos.add('+');
    opValidos.add('-');
    opValidos.add('*');
    opValidos.add('/');

    for (int i = 0; i < formula.length(); i++) {

        if (valores.contains(formula.charAt(i))) {

            numeros.add(formula.charAt(i));

        } else if (opValidos.contains(formula.charAt(i))) {

            op.add(formula.charAt(i));

        }

    }

}

public double resolve() {

    if (op.contains('*') || op.contains('/')) {

        arrumaExpressao();

    }

    int resultado = Character.getNumericValue(numeros.get(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < op.size(); i++) {

        if (op.get(i) == '+') {

            resultado += Character.getNumericValue(numeros.get(i + 1));

        } else if (op.get(i) == '-') {

            resultado -= Character.getNumericValue(numeros.get(i + 1));

        } else if (op.get(i) == '*') {

            resultado *= Character.getNumericValue(numeros.get(i + 1));

        } else if (op.get(i) == '/') {

            resultado /= Character.getNumericValue(numeros.get(i + 1));

        }

    }

    return resultado;
}

public void arrumaExpressao() {

    for (Character op1 : op) {

        if (op.contains('*')) {
            int i = op.indexOf('*');

            Collections.swap(op, 0, i);
            Collections.swap(numeros, 0, i);
            Collections.swap(numeros, 1, i + 1);
        }

        if (op.contains('/')) {
            int i = op.indexOf('/');

            Collections.swap(op, 0, i);
            Collections.swap(numeros, 0, i);
            Collections.swap(numeros, 1, i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Se quiser dar uma olhada no junit e na classe, você pode encontrar no meu github, bem como darem sugestões.

https://github.com/GustavoEmmel/Aulas